# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView View Recycling Issues

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I am using a CollectionView to display a list of entities that, when pressed, toggle between a opened and closed state. I did this by animating the HeightRequest parameter of the parent container of the view that was pressed, then adding whatever views I wanted to show in the view's expanded state. Here is the code snippet for that:

```
var animate = new Animation(d => this.HeightRequest = d,
    this.Bounds.Height, this.Bounds.Height + 300, Easing.CubicOut);
animate.Commit(this, "a", length: 500);

this.layout.Children.Add(this.candidateList);
this.layout.Children.Add(this.openButton);
```

This works fine, however, if I scroll down the list, I see that there are views that are also expanded even though I did not touch them previously, more so every full page of scrolling later. Some even include the views that I've added to the expanded state, showing incorrect data. I have assumed that this is due to the recycling mechanics of the CollectionView work in order to save on rendering costs, but there must be some way to fix this. Here is the code for relevant views:

```
var officesList = new CollectionView
{
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(OfficeListView)),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
    {
        SnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.None,
        ItemSpacing = 10,
    },
    Margin = new Thickness(20, 5),
    ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureAllItems,
    Footer = " ",
    FooterTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        return new StackLayout
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(20, 10),
            Children = {
                new LocorumLabels.MediumLabel
                {
                    Text = "x Results | No filters applied" //TODO: Bind these to footer
                }
            }
        };
    })


};
```

The next snippet is the CollectionsView within an expanded "Office":

```
this.candidateList = new CollectionView
{
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CandidateDetailView)),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
    {
        SnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.None,
        //ItemSpacing = 10,
    },
    Margin = new Thickness(10, 5),
    ItemSizingStrategy = ItemSizingStrategy.MeasureAllItems,
    Footer = " ",
    HeightRequest = 300

};
```

And here is a video showing what is going on:
https://youtu.be/Ltg2o8BwfwY

Hopefully someone can let me know of a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you invoked the animate in UI thread  .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Doesn't seem to have worked. I am going to switch my approach to this issue since this is proving to be a hard challenge. Instead of changing layout within the CollectionView, I will use an Rg.PopupPage to display the expanded view separate from the CollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on the cause.

As `CollectionView` uses `DataTemplate` you need to set your views and your data in such a way that when recycled the view appears as it should.

The non-obvious part to keep the animation working is to call the animation as of now but when it completes to set the value in data that would alter the view from the state before the animation to the state after the animation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I do have a state field in my DataTemplate object, but I only used it to keep track of if the view is to be opened or closed. Couple questions: when I scroll down my list, is the view that is being scrolled to created as a new object (while the views I scrolled off of are garbage collected)? Does this mean that I need code in my constructor that says "Hey, your state is Expanded, therefore you need this size" or do I put it elsewhere?

Comment: @MarcusOrciuch in simple words you need to make it work without animation first and then just where needed add animation and postpone setting of data until animation is completed.

Comment: So I found that every time a new view is shown in my CollectionsView, the constructor is called, so I created a method that will try and size the view depending on the binding context object's state. This method is called at the end of the contructor and a TapGesture callback. I pass one bool as a parameter to have the state change be animated, like when it is tapped. However, it still doesn't seem to work. It still behaves like the original video and (with the use of a breakpoint) the constructor seems to be called as I scroll at random intervals. Also sorry for the late response.

Comment: Also I put a breakpoint on the lines that create that inner CollectionsView and it breaks when I tap that first control. Theorically from what you're saying it should also break once I scroll down to that random view that mocks that original view (since this view is being created and my layout method is being called), however, it does not break when this happens.